# JUnit and aspectJ not working together

Tags: java, junit, aspectj, jvm-arguments, javaagents

I'm using aspectJ with load time weaving.

In order to execute my tomcat server I need to add the jvm arguments:

```
-javaagent:spring-instrument-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar
```

The server runs with the weaving perfectly.

problem is when i try to run my junit tests, all of them fails with weaving error.
the weaving error occurs if i don't provide the jvm arguments for the server as well.

so its pretty likely that when i run the junit tests the agent is not being called.

how exactly can i configure executing junit with jvm arguments?

thanks

Comment: How do you run your unit tests ? (From eclipse? Command line? Maven? Ant?...)

Comment: Im running them from eclipse

Answer (score 1):

OK, Its working:

right click on project - > properties - > edit\create new - > arguments -> add the javaagent line.